# Anomaly detection

Tags: classification, normal-distribution, anomaly-detection

I am trying to categorize the functionality of batteries in one kind of device. I am using linear models to find the functionality of batteries over time (considering other variables in the device that uses the battery). Then I get the lm coefficient of battery over time and I am assuming that the batteris functionality should be normally distributed (since it is factory made) which I see it too. The goal is to not only categorize their functionality but also detect anomalies.

I know I can use SVM algorithm to detect the anomalies but I dont think svm is the correct algorithm for it since I know what a good battery should be almost and the distribution is Gaussian. So I decided to categorize batteries :

1. Good: if lm coefficients are within the 1SD from mean of distribution (n=4266)
2. Bad: if 1SD < lm Coefficient < 2SD (n=229)
3. Anomaly: if lm coefficient is less than 2SD (n=160)

I am not sure if this is a naive criteria? What do you think?

[image: The distribution of LM coefficients]

Comment: What is denoted as SD? If it is standard deviation, you either 1) estimated standard deviation in a non-robust way, or 2) your distribution of lm coefficient is not normal.

Comment: Yes it standard deviation. 2) it is skewed but so basically starts from the mean of the normal distribution. But what do you suggest to me to do?

Comment: How about using probablity function of normal distribution and applying an epsilon to decide which PF is good and which one is anomaly?

Comment: At first, I would not rely on normality here. If you have 4266 + 229 + 160 points, there should be ~3100 points within the interval of 1SD under normality assumption, not >4000. I would find a probability model that "look alike" your distribution, fit it in a robust way and remove all results that have adjusted p-value < 0.05 (or any other threshold)

Comment: upd: your distribution (based on the plot) is not even close to normal. try to find a rationale to use smth like zero-inflated gamma distribution.

Comment: One question here: Gamma distribution is for positive values and my lm coefficients are negative. Should I just simply multiplie them by -1 and then use gamma distribution?

Comment: I am not saying that gamma distribution is the ideal choice. If I were you I would try to understand which stochastic process models your data and this understanding will tell you which distribution to use. I am not even sure that it is a correct way to deal with lm coefficients and are your linear models valid. But yes, if I wanted to fit this distribution with gamma - I would multiply it by -1.

Comment: I used EM algorithm instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your idea looks good to me. (I was not able to add a comment - hence attempting an 'Answer')

If I understand correctly: Battery performance degrades over time and hence you have a -ve lm coefficients.

Some observations based on the plot:

- Extremely narrow "bell" - so the SD is probably very small
- The avg. seems to be about -2.0, and then it has a really long tail.
- So it appears to me that you will have a lot of "anomalies" based on your guidelines - where as generally shouldn't anomalies be a small percentage?
- Also there appears to be a hump with coefficient = 0, so I guess those batteries showed a performance that appear flat over time - i.e. NO degradation over time. I wonder if those are due to incorrect data readings? Are those anomalies too? And would your criteria catch them?

Comment: it does not look like "bell" at all. At first, where is the right tail of the "bell". It is just non-normal data.

Comment: @RajeshS no I dont have any criteria about the percentage of the anomalies so it can be as many as I can detect. I should mention some important fact about these batteries that they are being recharged by solar panels so the hump at zero is those that are being recharged almost as much as they are being used. I can first remove those but the problem here is I cannot take care of solar recharging since we dont have any information when and how much it can happen. And we dont care about those anyway since they are not being considered as bad batteries anyway.

Comment: And I use LOESS smoothing so if the battery level is 100% for a quite several days or if only one day has been recharged, this smoothing method changes the battery level a bit to fit a smooth linear model on top of it.